# SELECT MAX(), COUNT() returning wrong values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a strange problem here. Suddenly one of my tables stopped giving the correct results to very simple queries.
My app does something like this:

```
nextNumber = SELECT(max) numero from table + 1;
```

When numero reached 12,000 it simply started returning 11995 as the anwser to SELECT MAX(numero) from table. numero is a INTEGER column, with no checks, indexes, nothing, a standard int column.

[image: Result from very simple queries]

Note that the app kept working, and added 36 new lines, all of them with numero = 11996 (11995 returned from SELECT MAX(numero) + 1)

[image: By always returning 11995 as the result to SELECT MAX, new lines used the same value for the new rows inserted after id 25672]

I've done a lot of research, tried deleting the database logs, transaction logs, shrink database, but nothing has worked so far. What can be causing something like that ?

Comment: try this `Select Max(Cast(Numero as bigint)) as [Top Numero] from baixatitulos` and tell me if there is any difference

Comment: Try without nolock

Comment: This conundrum looks interesting. What is the result of those queries if you remove the NOLOCK? Dirty reads can be a filty thing if you depend on them to get a next number.

Comment: Would you app be able to use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) ?

Comment: Uncommitted transactions can make strange things happen. Does `DBCC OPENTRAN` show anything?

Comment: Sorry I didn't add this info on the original question, but using NOLOCK or not using it makes no difference.
CAST to BIGINT makes no difference too.
DBCC OPENTRAN says there is no transactions open

Comment: can you try this please and let us know if it gives correct output? `SELECT * FROM table where numero = 11996`

Comment: SELECT * FROM BaixaTitulos WHERE numero = 11996 returns 0 rows
SELECT * FROM BaixaTitulos WHERE numero > 11995 returns 0 rows too ...
This is jus bizarre

Comment: If, inside you app, you run the `select max...` and the insert query separately, there is a chance that all running instances of your app get the same value, then insert that value.

Comment: try 1 more query -> `SELECT * FROM table where id = 25673` and tell what is the value in `numero` column

Comment: @AndréCasteliano. . . This is the internal cache you need to close your current session or also try to log out server & then re-login again.

Comment: SELECTing by the Id returns the correct row. SELECT ... WHERE id = 25673 returns numero = 11996

Comment: There is no cache, 1 DB per app instance. Right now I've restored a backup of the database on my local machine and I'm running the test queries using Management Studio.

Comment: @AndréCasteliano can you share DDL query?

Comment: CREATE TABLE BaixaTitulos
(
 id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
 metadata INTEGER NOT NULL,
 empresa INTEGER,
 numero INTEGER,
 situacao INTEGER,

        ... (had to remove due to character limit on SO)
 FOREIGN KEY(metadata) REFERENCES Metadata(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(empresa) REFERENCES Empresas(id),
);

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of tests, I found the problem was the corruption of the database data file, and only running a DBCC CHECKDB with the REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS parameter I was able to restore the offending table to 'normal'.